# How to access an array retrieved from controller via AJAX

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I call an MVC controller via Java and AJAX.  The data goes to the controller, the controller returns a List. How do I access that list?  This may seem trivial, but I can't find it anywhere on google or SO.  Most of the examples I've found call for using:

```
...
success: function (r) {
    var exemptions = r.d;
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < exemptions.length; i++){
        ddlist.appent('<option>' + exemptions[i] + '</option>');
    ....
    }
```

That method, however, results in this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success (6:281)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Controller Method:

```
        public JsonResult GetValidRecords(int year) 
        {
            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var Exemptions = model.Permits.Where(m => m.Year == year).OrderBy(m => m.Exemption).OrderBy(m => m.Year).ToList();
            foreach (Permit x in Exemptions)
            {
                items.Insert(items.Count, new SelectListItem { Text = x.Exemption.ToString(), Value = x.Exemption.ToString() });
            }
            return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The dropdown box:

```
        <text>EXEMPTION RENEWAL FORM</text>
        <select id="dd" name="dd" onchange="CallRenewalReport(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Year First</option>
        </select>
        @Html.DropDownList("ddldate", new SelectList(Model.RYearList, "ID", "Year", "Select a year"), new { @onchange = "GetGoodRecords(this.value)", @AppendDataBoundItems = "False" })
        break;
```

The JavaScript/AJAX query:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetGoodRecords(val) {
            alert(val);
                var year = val;
                var RootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';

            $.ajax({
                url: RootUrl + "Reports/GetValidRecords",
                data: { year: year },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var exemptions = response.d;
                    var ddlist = $('#dd');
                    ddlist.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Exemption</option>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < exemptions.length; i++) {
                        ddlist.append('<option>' + exemptions[i] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Can anyone spell this out to me in layman's terms?

Regards,

Carthax

Comment: What is the 'd' property of your response?  Does you returned JSON have a 'd' property?  It looks like you are returning a collection, and that your result would be a JSON array.  I think you want to use 'response.length', not 'response.d.length'

Comment: @MikeMarshall Like I said, I have been basing this off of things I've found on the web.  I'm learning this on my own, from scratch.  Some things, like this, appear to be so easy that there is little reference to it on google.

Comment: @MikeMarshall: Changing that to response[i] does, at least, fill the dropdownlist.  ...it fills it with "[object Object]," but it does fill it.  Thank you for getting me a bit farther down the road.

Comment: @MikeMarshall, dude, you're brilliant.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In case someone happens upon this question in google)

Based on input from @MikeMarshall, here is the solution that works:

The controller action is correct, but I'm putting it all in one place so you don't have to copy-and-paste from all over the page

```
 public JsonResult GetValidRecords(int year) 
        {
            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var Exemptions = model.Permits.Where(m => m.Year == year).OrderBy(m => m.Exemption).OrderBy(m => m.Year).ToList();
            foreach (Permit x in Exemptions)
            {
                items.Insert(items.Count, new SelectListItem { Text = x.Exemption.ToString(), Value = x.Exemption.ToString() });
            }
            return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The razor code:

```
<text>EXEMPTION RENEWAL FORM</text>
        <select id="dd" name="dd" onchange="CallRenewalReport(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Year First</option>
        </select>
        @Html.DropDownList("ddldate", new SelectList(Model.RYearList, "ID", "Year", "Select a year"), new { @onchange = "GetRecords(this.value)", @AppendDataBoundItems = "False" })
        break;
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetRecords(val) {
            alert(val);
                var year = val;
                var RootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';

            $.ajax({
                url: RootUrl + "Reports/GetValidRecords",
                data: { year: year },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    // get the dropdownlist
                    var ddlist = $('#dd');
                    // empty the dropdownlist and add "Select Exemption"
                    ddlist.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Exemption</option>');
                    // for each value in the response
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        // properly query the Value and Text fields in the array
                        ddlist.append('<option value="' + response[i].Value + '">' + response[i].Text + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot in your success function:

```
success: function (response) {
             for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                 var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response[i]));
                 alert(obj.Text);
              }
          }
```

This will show an alert of what is contained in each object of the response array.